# How to get data from previous record in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called `items`. Now, I'm getting all the records of the current week (means record each day). I've already done that.

But the problem is, if there is no record on let's say Wednesday, the data of Wednesday should still be the data of Tuesday Or the date before the Wednesday. Please see my code below.

```
public function arrayAssigner($theArray, $theArrayData, $field)
{
    $format_to_day = function($date){
        return date_format(new \DateTime($date), 'D');
    };

    foreach($theArray as $key => $value){
        if(isset($theArrayData[$key]) && $format_to_day($theArrayData[$key]['created_at']) == 'Mon'){
            $theArray[0] = $theArrayData[$key][$field];
        } elseif (isset($theArrayData[$key]) && $format_to_day($theArrayData[$key]['created_at']) == 'Tue'){
            $theArray[1] = $theArrayData[$key][$field];
        } elseif (isset($theArrayData[$key]) && $format_to_day($theArrayData[$key]['created_at']) == 'Wed'){
            $theArray[2] = $theArrayData[$key][$field];
        } elseif (isset($theArrayData[$key]) && $format_to_day($theArrayData[$key]['created_at']) == 'Thu'){
            $theArray[3] = $theArrayData[$key][$field];
        } elseif (isset($theArrayData[$key]) && $format_to_day($theArrayData[$key]['created_at']) == 'Fri'){
            $theArray[4] = $theArrayData[$key][$field];
        }
    }

    return $theArray;
}
```

I used it like this:

```
$theArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
$this->arrayAssigner($theArray, $dataOfTheWeek, 'quantity');
```

I also have a constructor to set the weekStart at **MONDAY**.

**Example**:

Let's say I have a record from `Nov 12 - 16`. Now, the current week is `Nov 26-30`, but in the database I don't have a record on `Nov 26`, it means, the record or the quantity of `Nov 26` is the record from `Nov 16`.

**Output (as array)**:
Nov 12 - 16: 
`[7, 5, 6, 8, 12]`

Nov 26 - 30: 
`[12, 8, 9, 10, 13]`

The first item in the array of `Nov 26 - 30` should be 12, since it is the previous data of `Nov 12 - 16`.

Support Image:

[image]

The result must be dynamic; Once there is a day that has no record, it will filled with the last record.

Comment: I assume you want others to help modifying the `arrayAssigner` to return certain result, right? In that case, I'd suggest you to provide examples of input(s) and current output(s) and expected output(s)

Comment: @YohanesGultom Please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function arrayAssigner($theArray, $theArrayData, $field) {

    $format_to_day = function($date){
        return date_format(new \DateTime($date), 'D');
    };

    foreach($theArray as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($theArrayData[$key])) {
            $day = $format_to_day($theArrayData[$key]['created_at']);

            switch ($day) {
                case 'Mon':
                    $theArray[0] = $theArrayData[$key][$field];
                break;
                case 'Tue':
                    // new_data  = ---if exists ---------------v--- assign ------------------v-- old_data--
                    $theArray[1] = $theArrayData[$key][$field] ? $theArrayData[$key][$field] : $theArray[0];
                break;
                case 'Wed':
                    // new_data  = ---if exists ---------------v--- assign ------------------v-- old_data--
                    $theArray[2] = $theArrayData[$key][$field] ? $theArrayData[$key][$field] : $theArray[1];
                break;
                case 'Thu':
                    // new_data  = ---if exists ---------------v--- assign ------------------v-- old_data--
                    $theArray[3] = $theArrayData[$key][$field] ? $theArrayData[$key][$field] : $theArray[2];
                break;
                case 'Fri':
                    // new_data  = ---if exists ---------------v--- assign ------------------v-- old_data--
                    $theArray[4] = $theArrayData[$key][$field] ? $theArrayData[$key][$field] : $theArray[3];
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $theArray;
}
```

Is this what you want???

Comment: Not exactly what I want. What if 'Mon' has no record? 'Mon' should get the last record before it (e.g. Nov 23 or other date that has a record before the 'Mon').

Comment: yes I know that... Can you mention where is the record of previous week???

Comment: I mean what actually are you sending in the `$theArrayData` Is it like `[ '26/11/2018', '27/11/2018', ... , '30/11/2018' ]` **???**